# Xamarin.forms.maps not visible in UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, invisible

I am new to Xamarin.forms and need to use maps for UWP platform. I have installed Xamarin.Forms.Maps nuget package in my PCL. And have called the init function in the App.xaml.cs of UWP section as follows:

### Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e); Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("TokenKey");

However, the maps is not visible on deploying. I have added some pins as well and what I see is some blue screen, with the pins. I have tried lot of options, but have found no luck yet.
 Below is the code snippet for calling maps:

```
Map map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(51.5074, 0.1278), Distance.FromMiles(10)));
        map.MapType = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.MapType.Hybrid;
        map.HeightRequest = 700;
        map.WidthRequest = 725;
        map.IsShowingUser = true;
        var position1 = new Position(51.5033, 0.1195);
        var pin1 = new Pin { Type = PinType.Place, Position = position1, Label = "label1", Address = "address1" };
        map.Pins.Add(pin1);
        var position2 = new Position(51.5014, 0.1419);
        var pin2 = new Pin { Type = PinType.Place, Position = position2, Label = "label1", Address = "address1" };
        map.Pins.Add(pin2);
        this.mapGrid.Children.Add(map);
```

Am I doing anything wrong ? Or is there any missing reference that I should be adding to make this work ? Please help me out.
P.S- The same solution loads a map on my colleague's machine, but doesn't work on others' machines.

Regards,
Swati

Please find below a screenshot of my UWP references :
[UWP reference screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvThS.png)

[UWP Nuget package reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiD0A.png)

Comment: Can you share your UWP configuration? From the documentation, it looks like you may need some service-locator magic with the appropriate settings in each platform: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/#Platform_Configuration

Comment: Thanks Joe. I am not sure of how can I find the UWP configuration. Updated my query by adding a screenshot of my UWP references here.

Comment: Also as suggested in the link (referred by you), I am already using an auth token key :(

Comment: Have you checked the [official sample here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/)? It works by my side, and from your description: "The same solution loads a map on my colleague's machine, but doesn't work on others' machines.", you mean on some machine your code works and others not?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add using System.Reflection for this solution to work.

This appears to be a known challenge with some framework and UWP.  In the UWP project's App.Xaml.cs, in the OnLaunched event, AFTER the following line of code:

```
rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
```

Add
            List assembliesToInclude = new List();

```
        //Now, add all the assemblies your app uses
        assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms.UWP.SfRatingRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.UWP.MapRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
```

Ensure the ...Forms.Init line shown here REPLACES the save existing call to the initializer in your code.

Answer (score -1):

you need need to enable the google map API on your Google APIs console